# How to handle two consecutive and dependent Async calls in Redux?

Tags: redux

I am getting a list of posts asynchronously by calling an action `fetchPosts` from a Component on `componentDidMount`. I would like, once that request is received and handled by the relevant reducer (which updates the state), to call another action `fetchPostsMetaData`, with an array of the just-received posts' ids.

I am using `redux-thunk` middleware, and making my ajax requests using `jQuery.ajax`

What is the best way to go about this? I tried googling but couldn't find a relevant example / answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `redux-thunk`:

```
class PostIndex extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }
  ...
}

function fetchPosts() {
  return dispatch => {
    fetchPostsAjax()
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_POSTS', payload: res });
        dispatch(fetchPostMeta(res));
      })
  }
}

function fetchPostMeta(posts) {
  return dispatch => {
    fetchPostMetaAjax(posts)
      .then(res => dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_POST_META', payload: res }));
    }
  }
}

function fetchPostAjax() {
   // return a promise, whether from jQuery.ajax or fetch
}

function fetchPostMetaAjax() {
  // return a promise
}
```

This is a pretty standard use-case for `redux-thunk`. The above example is catered towards the way you're asking the question, but you could accomplish this in a single action creator that looks the the `redux-thunk` example provided here: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Whats different is that in my example, I'm dispatching a thunk inside of a thunk, rather than doing the second task directly inside of the first thunk. So its equivalent to this:

```
function fetchPosts() {
  return dispatch => {
    fetchPostsAsync()
      .then(res => { // res is posts
        dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_POSTS', payload: res });
        return fetchPostMetaAsync(res);
      })
      .then(res => { // res  is metadata
        dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_POST_META', payload: res });
      })
  }
}
```

You won't run into any race conditions because when you dispatch an action like `{ type: RECEIVE_POSTS, payload: res }`, it is synchronous and the reducer updates before you dispatch the following async action.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work perfectly, and makes sense. Thanks! I ended up doing it like the second example you provided only replacing `then` with jQuery's `$.ajax({...success: function(result) { ... } })`. 

Also, you have a repeating `fetchPosts()` call in your first example, might want to edit the first one to `getPosts()` for it to be more comprehensible. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I I corrected it.I think the second example is more idiomatic and promises are fun so :thumbsup: