# how to assert an async action dispatched inside an async action in redux-thunk

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mocha.js, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to assert an async action is dispatched by an async action like so :

```
// synchronous actions
export const getObjects = () => ({ type: 'GET_OBJECTS' });
export const addObject = object => ({ type: 'ADD_OBJECT', object });

// an async action
export const getObjectsAsync = () => 
  dispatch =>
    axios.get(URL).then((data) => {
      dispatch(getObjects());
    });

// another async action that dispatches the previous async action
export const postObjectAsync = newObject =>
  dispatch =>
    axios.post(URL, newObject)
      .then(() => { dispatch(addObject(newObject)); })
      .then(() => { dispatch(getObjectAsync()); });

// the test
describe('postObjectAsync()', () => {
  it('should return ADD_OBJECT and GET_OBJECT actions', () => {
    const object = mockedObject;
    const store = mockedStore;
    const expectedActions = [
     { type: 'ADD_OBJECT', object },
     { type: 'GET_OBJECTS', objects }, // I expected to see this object on store.getActions()[1]
    ];
    return store.dispatch(postObjectAsync(object))
      .then(() => {
        store.getActions().should.deep.equal(expectedActions);
        // AssertionError: expected [ Array(1) ] to deeply equal [ Array(2) ]
      });
  });
});
```

I expected store.getActions() to contain an array with both the GET_OBJECTS and ADD_OBJECT actions inside it but it only contains the ADD_OBJECT action

Can anybody weigh in?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the problem is not in the test,

```
// another async action that dispatches the previous async action
export const postObjectAsync = newObject =>
  dispatch =>
    axios.post(URL, newObject)
      .then(() => { dispatch(addObject(newObject)); })
      .then(() => { dispatch(getObjectAsync()); });
```

should be

```
// another async action that dispatches the previous async action
export const postObjectAsync = newObject =>
  dispatch =>
    axios.post(URL, newObject)
      .then(() => { 
        dispatch(addObject(newObject));
        return dispatch(getObjectAsync());
      });
```

I just realized shouldn't use .then() on a synchronous function.
This post helped : [How to handle two consecutive and dependant async calls in redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342971/how-to-handle-two-consecutive-and-dependant-async-calls-in-redux)